# ORACLE PL/SQL: Calling stored procedure function with multiple parameters (DML query)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, stored-functions

New PL/SQL person here. I have a (successfully compiled) PL/SQL function block that manipulates a table in my database by adding a new term to it:

```
create or replace FUNCTION add_new_term
    (TERM_ID_IN IN NUMBER, TERM_IN IN VARCHAR2, IS_METATERM_IN IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    add_term CV_TERMS.TERM_NAME%TYPE; --TERM_NAME is VARCHAR2 type
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CV_TERMS (TERM_ID, TERM_NAME, IS_METATERM)
    VALUES (TERM_ID_IN, TERM_IN, IS_METATERM_IN);
    dbms_output.put_line('New term successfully added to CV_TERMS table: ' || TERM_IN);
    RETURN add_term;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'You have tried to insert a duplicate term.');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN    
        raise_application_error (-20002, 'An error has occurred inserting a term - '|| SQLCODE ||' -ERROR- '|| SQLERRM);
END add_new_term;
```

I call this function like calling a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE
  add_term_success cv_terms.term_name%type;
BEGIN
  add_term_success := add_new_term(cv_terms_pk.NEXTVAL, 'TESTTT', 0);
END;
```

SQLDeveloper tells me the procedure was successfully completed, however, the term has not been added to the table. I created the sequence `cv_terms_pk` independently (it's not in the table CV_TERMS' SQL). Does it need to be there? Am I passing it improperly? Or is something wrong with my `add_term` declaration? Ideas?

Comment: do you commit somewhere?

Comment: Did you query the table to verify it isn't there? I noticed that you are returning `add_term`, but never setting a value. Likewise, you are returning a line of output, but after you have already ceased execution due to the return. So your return value will always be `NULL` and no output will ever show up in the console.

Comment: @HepC I queried the table, indeed. They are writing to the table. Silly me. When I searched for them before within the table, they weren't showing up. So everything works except the console output. Could you explain a little more? I understand that I put the return line after the return (I switched it), but as far as setting a value to `add_term`?  @tbone I did not commit.

Comment: For getting a value into your return parameter, you just need to use the [RETURNING INTO](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354) clause, added to the end of your INSERT statement.

Comment: @HepC Got it, thanks. I would +1 you, but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Also, the Script Output in my SQLDev wasn't on, so I ran `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`. All lines are being returned now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the DML INSERT you have to commit the transaction.

```
create or replace FUNCTION add_new_term
(TERM_ID_IN IN NUMBER, TERM_IN IN VARCHAR2, IS_METATERM_IN IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
add_term CV_TERMS.TERM_NAME%TYPE; --TERM_NAME is VARCHAR2 type
```

`BEGIN
     INSERT INTO CV_TERMS(TERM_ID, TERM_NAME, IS_METATERM
      VALUES (TERM_ID_IN, TERM_IN, IS_METATERM_IN);
      COMMIT; ---LINE ADDED ...`

Comment: Thanks, I did this already :). Part of the issue was that my console wasn't returning any lines, so I had to `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` to get diagnostics. Marked as correct.